# Perl scalar operator on grepped list gives less value

Tags: perl

I was solving a project euler problem [problem 19](https://projecteuler.net/problem=19) that asks for the number of months from 01-01-1901 to 31-12-2000 that has their first day as a sunday. I learned about DateTime module to get day_name() for the date. I wrote a one line grep to do it

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
        say scalar grep {
            my $d = $_;
            grep {
                if ( DateTime->new( year => "$d", month => "$_", day => "1" )->day_name() =~ /monday/i ) {
                    say "$_ : $d";
                }
            } ( 1 .. 12 )
        } ( 1901 .. 2000 );
    '
```

It gives 100 as answer but it prints 172 lines. I also tried replacing `say "$_ : $d";` with `(1)` and still it shows the 100. Also for 1901 to 1903 6 days are present it shows 3 . I tried MO=Deparse but don't see anything wrong. So I had to couple it with wc to get the output.

```
perl -E 'say scalar grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } (1..100)' 

output : 

50
```

why was my grep giving me incorrect values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print in the inner grep, but return `scalar` of the outer grep which iterates over the years. There are 100 matching years, so the answer is correct.

To use your idea, you have to iterate over the dates (years and months combined) and count matches. For that, you can use `map`:

```
use Time::Piece;
say scalar grep 'Monday' eq 'Time::Piece'->strptime("$_ 1", '%Y %m %d')->fullday,
           map {
               my $y = $_;
               map "$y $_", 1 .. 12
           } 1901 .. 2000;
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba . I can get it now with `perl -MDateTime -MList::Util -E 'say List::Util::reduce { $a + $b } map { my $d = $_; scalar grep { DateTime->new(year => "$d",month => "$_", day => "2")->day_name() =~ /monday/i } (1..12) }(1901..2000) ; '` . Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the purpose of [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

Use the former if you want to transform the list, and the latter if you want to filter it.

The following is a fix of your script:

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E '
    say scalar grep { $_->day_name() =~ /monday/i }
        map {
            my $y = $_;
            map DateTime->new( year => $y, month => $_, day => 1 ), ( 1 .. 12 )
        } ( 1901 .. 2000 );
    '
172
```